# How to create a percent on a column graph chart?

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a column graph chart in SSRS 2008 R2 and now I want to display the values as a percent.  Currently it just displays the sum totals.  My dataset looks like:

```
people_count    facility    met_reqs
12  Chattanooga, TN 0
9   Clarksville, TN 0
6   Columbia, TN    0
51  Chattanooga, TN 1
22  Clarksville, TN 1
28  Columbia, TN    1
```

As you can see, each city has two rows: the first row is the count of persons who did not meet requirements and the second row is for each city which did meet reqs.

```
Where my last query is:
select 
count(distinct people_id) as people_count,
facility,
case when total_los/total_visits *3/7 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end met_reqs
from #final
group by facility, case when total_los/total_visits *3/7 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end
```

Currently I have this chart to display the sum of people_count for Chart Values, Category Group = facility, and Series Group = met_reqs.

This looks like:
[image]

But now for the Y-axis I want this to instead display percentage of persons/facility who met the requirements.  How can I do this?  So the Y-axis should instead have a range of 0-100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a **100 % Stacked Column** chart?

[image]

If you change your existing setup this seems to achieve your requirements:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If this isn't what you're after, can you please update your questions with some more details?

**Edit after comment**

OK, to meet the specific requirement of displaying % Meeting Requirements only. With the same Dataset, use a Chart type of *Column* (i.e. the first option) and remove the **Series Group**:

[image]

[image]

Change the **Values** expression to:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!met_reqs.Value = 1, Fields!people_count.Value, Nothing))
    / Sum(Fields!people_count.Value)
```

i.e. getting the % of total `people_count` where `met_reqs` = *1* compared to the total `people_count` in each group.

For the sake of completeness I changed the number formatting on the Y axis to be percentage.

This looks OK to me:

[image]

Hopefully this help get a bit closer to the goal.

Comment: Thanks.  Great idea, but she just wants to see % that met expectations.  How could I do that?

Comment: OK, I've added some more detail - hopefully this works for you?